# Collection of Collection of UIViews

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

In my Swift app I have 9 outlets:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var day1: UIImageView!
 @IBOutlet weak var day1Title: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var day1Description: UILabel!

 @IBOutlet weak var day2: UIImageView!
 @IBOutlet weak var day2Title: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var day2Description: UILabel!

 @IBOutlet weak var day3: UIImageView!
 @IBOutlet weak var day3Title: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var day3Description: UILabel!
```

I'd like to "group" these together by their day using an integer as the key. So 1 maps to day1, day1Title, day1Description.

So that I could assign label text to each of the above generically rather than have to reference the specific image view, label, and description.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

I thought maybe:

```
 Dictionary<int, Array<UIImageView, UILabel, UILabel>>
```

or

```
 Dictionary<int, Array<UIView>>
```

but i'm not quite sure about this being the right move. Could I somehow assign a class that has 3 properties that reference these outlets maybe?

Or perhaps 3 outlet collections?

What do you think is good to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use a dictionary with an integer key? An array of 9 elements should work just as well. In addition, the value would be better represented as a tuple instead of as an array.

```
 Array<(UIImageView, UILabel, UILabel)>
```

or

```
[(UIImageView, UILabel, UILabel)]
```

result

```
var views: [(UIImageView, UILabel, UILabel)]

…

views = [(day1, day1Title, day1Description),
         (day2, day2Title, day2Description),
         …
         (day9, day9Title, day9Description)]

…

var (imageView, titleLabel, descriptionLabel) = views[dayNumber - 1]
```